# Check two values if it exists in another sheet and highlight them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help to find two values in another sheet and highlight them.

Conditions are as follows:

1. If code AND projects exist (highlight column A and column C) OR
2. If code exists, (highlight column A) OR
3. If project exists (highlight column C)
4. Else, leave as white

So far, it only highlights the code (column A if there is a matching value) and I am unable to execute item 1 and 3 above. Any input on this is appreciated. TIA!

[image]

```
function checkDups() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var formLR = form.getLastRow();
  var formRange = form.getRange(2, 1, formLR - 1, form.getLastColumn());
  var formValue = formRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < formValue.length; i++) {
    var code = formValue[i][0]; 
    var product = formValue[i][2];

    /* Where to check the values */
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    var sheet2LR = sheet2.getLastRow(); 
    var sheet2Range = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2LR - 1, 2);
    var sheet2Value = sheet2Range.getValues();

    for (var j = 0; j < sheet2Value.length; j++) {
      var indexCode = sheet2Value[j][0];
      var indexProd = sheet2Value[j][1];

      /* If project code already exists, mark it as red (duplicate) */
      if ((code === indexCode) || (product === indexProd) || (code === indexCode && product === indexProd)) {
         form.getRange(i + 2, 1).setBackground('red');
       }
       else {
         form.getRange(i + 2, 1).setBackground('white');
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The chances are pretty good that even if you get a highlight by the time you reach the bottom of sheet2 it's going to be turned back to white.  If you get a highlight perhaps you should break.  You also have to consider that they both could be null and still be equal. Try using the debugger and single step through the script paying close attention to each value.

Comment: I would break up the conditions into more decisions (ie more if elses)

Comment: BTW you explanation uses the term projects but your image has the header of Product

Comment: I think, I got it to work...not too pretty but it works for the conditions set above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkdups() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var vs2 = sh2.getRange(2, 1, sh2.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  vs1.forEach(([a1, , c1], i) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < vs2.length; j++) {
      let [a2, c2] = vs2[j];
      if (a1 && a1 === a2 && c1 && c1 === c2) {
        sh1.getRange(i + 2, 1).setBackground('red');
        sh1.getRange(i + 2, 3).setBackground('red');
        break;
      } else if (a1 && a1 == a2) {
        sh1.getRange(i + 2, 1).setBackground('red');
        break;
      } else if (c1 && c1 == c2) {
        sh1.getRange(i + 2, 3).setBackground('red');
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDups() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var formLR = form.getLastRow();
  var formRange = form.getRange(2, 1, formLR - 1, form.getLastColumn());
  var formValue = formRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < formValue.length; i++) {
    var code = formValue[i][0]; 
    var product = formValue[i][2];

    /* Where to check the values */
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    var sheet2LR = sheet2.getLastRow(); 
    var sheet2Range = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2LR - 1, 2);
    var sheet2Value = sheet2Range.getValues();

    for (var j = 0; j < sheet2Value.length; j++) {
      var indexCode = sheet2Value[j][0];
      var indexProd = sheet2Value[j][1];

      /* If code exists, mark it as red (duplicate) */
      if ((code === indexCode && product === indexProd)) {
        form.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 3).setBackgrounds([['red',null, 'red']]);
      } else if (code === indexCode) {
        form.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).setBackground('red');
      } else if (product === indexProd) {
        form.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 3).setBackgrounds([[null, null, 'red']]);
      } else {
        form.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 3).setBackgrounds([[null, null, null]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another approach, how about using objects for searching values and the range list for giving a background color of the cell as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
function checkdups2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const range1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:C" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  const values1 = range1.getDisplayValues();
  const values2 = sheet2.getRange("A2:B" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  
  // Create objects.
  const { a, b } = values2.reduce((o, [aa, bb]) => {
    o.a[aa] = bb;
    o.b[bb] = aa;
    return o;
  }, { a: {}, b: {} });
  
  // Create range list.
  const rangeList = values1.reduce((ar, [aa, , cc], i) => {
    if (aa && cc && a[aa] == cc && b[cc] == aa) {
      ar.push(`A${i + 2}`, `C${i + 2}`);
    } else if (aa && a[aa]) {
      ar.push(`A${i + 2}`);
    } else if (cc && b[cc]) {
      ar.push(`C${i + 2}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // Set background colors.
  if (rangeList.length == 0) return;
  range1.setBackground(null);
  sheet1.getRangeList(rangeList).setBackground("red");
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))